# Search a Lotus Notes database from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, lotus-notes

I am trying to search a Lotus Notes database from PowerShell and getting a `"Type Mismatch. (Exception from HResult: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH)" At line 1: char:1`.

Set-up code:

```
$notesSession = New-Object -ComObject Lotus.NotesSession
$notesSession.Initialize()
$notesDb = $notesSession.GetDatabase(..., ...)
```

I get the errors when trying...

```
$results = $notesDb.Search("text", $null, 0)
$results = $notesDb.Search("text", $(Get-Date), 0)
$results = $notesDb.Search("text", $([System.DateTime]::Now), 0)
```

Can anybody spot the mistake? I think the error is to do with the date argument, hence my multiple attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems to be coming from the fact that [`.Search` wants a `notesDateTime` object for that parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_SEARCH_METHOD.html). So in theory you just need to create a `notesdatetime` object and pass that to the search method.

```
$searchDate = $notesSession.CreateDateTime(get-date -f "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

I am not in a position to test this nor am I sure how to get a null return from this short of passing $null to the CreateDateTime method.

[Unsure if this is the correct reference for the COM implementation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_CREATEDATETIME_METHOD.html) but from the parameter section

> The date and time you want the object to represent. If you use an empty string (""), the date is set to a wildcard date. The Notes date-time expressions "Today," "Tomorrow" and "Yesterday" are supported.

Comment: Educated guess this is your issue. Might not have a workable solution though. I will delete this if I am incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the `.CreateDateTime` method, silly me. Getting a Formula Error now! The battle continues...